# 18.04 LTS - What was wrong with the December 11 pulseaudio update?

Tags: 18.04, pulseaudio, configuration-management

On December 11 my 18.04 LTS systems received an update of `pulseaudio` from version 7.2 to version 7.5

However, on December 12, version 7.5 was deleted from the repos in favor of version 7.4.

What was wrong with the version of this software that was distributed on the 11th, and what risk am I incurring by running this version on my LTS machines?

Downgrading to 7.4 does not appear to be a simple process, at least for systems running Lubuntu.

Comment: Good question!  I don't know if it is answerable due to no changelog available for that version.  The only changelog I can see is `apt changelog pulseaudio=1:11.1-1ubuntu7.4` and that has nothing listed in it.  Maybe once 7.6 is released it might be listed in the change log.  On my system the 7.5 version seems to be working fine.

Comment: I haven't noticed any problems either, but it makes me nervous when they do this. I was able to downgrade a more-or-less stock Ubuntu system using `aptitude`, but my Lubuntu systems are more problematic.

Comment: Does it count that I filed a question about it?  :)  https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+question/687128

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a question I asked at https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+question/687128 looks like 7.5 has problems with snaps

> see https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+publishinghistory
>
> Removal requested on 2019-12-12. Deleted on 2019-12-12
>
> buggy SRU, pulls snapd due to the lib Recommends

and

> See also
>   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1856054

Comment: *sigh* I hate snaps.

Comment: @OrganicMarble You and me both!  =)

Comment: As of 4/22/20 it appears that version 7.5 is finally back in bionic.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yep, looks like they republished it:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1856054/comments/14