# Is updating Ubuntu riskier than not?

Tags: 18.04, apt, updates, security

In the past six months, my computer became unusable twice (couldn't login) as a consequence of an update. (A regular update, done by `apt-get upgrade` in the terminal).

I was able to troubleshoot and solve it the first time, but in the second I had to reinstall the OS (18.04).

This is annoying to say the least, so I am considering not updating my Ubuntu from now on, since now it is working fine, and I'm afraid it will stop working if I update it. I am not sure why this happens, but I do know that my laptop is not very "Linux-friendly" (it had no wifi or sound when I first installed it etc).

**Question:** Is this risky for some reason? Will I miss out on important stability updates that may render my computer useless again? In other words: update or not?

Comment: To be safer from borking your system when updating you could use an lvm setup with snapshots, as described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/424225/setting-up-lvm-snapshot-as-a-backup-restore-point-in-ubuntu/680451#680451

Comment: It's also important to be conscious of any changes you make that might have potential adverse effects on the system. My friend had a similar complaint and it turned out he'd tampered with his python installation.

Comment: @NonnyMoose Yes I actually think that is what happened to me as well.

Comment: `apt-get upgrade` alone doesn't upgrade anything. That is why we run `update` first. It lets apt know that newer versions exist. _Then_ `upgrade` will go for those newer versions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Letting your installed OS get out of date raises the risk that a security flaw that was unknown the last time you installed or updated, but discovered (by black hat types) later, may not get fixed, leaving your system open to exploits, potentially including using your processor to mine cryptocurrency, making it part of a botnet used for hacking attacks or denial of service, stealing your private information stored in your system (including passwords for things like your bank and email), or installing ransomware.

A better path, if you have reason to suspect unreliable updates, is to delay installing updates.  Many IT departments do this with their Windows updates, to be sure they won't promptly and broadly install one that bricks their hardware (been known to happen!).

The potential problem with Ubuntu and other Linux distros in this regard is there's no simple way to "sudo apt update-to-october".  One way you might do this is to *download* the update files promptly, but hold them in a sort of quarantine for a period of time to watch for reports of problems before installing.  Self-reminders using `cron` will help keep your schedule.

Comment: This is not limited to Linux and Windows - the recent Catalina update to Apple also 'broke' many programs, until they were updated to handle the new OS, prompting many IT people to advise delaying system updates to a later date.

Comment: +1, after being burned once too many times I finally took this approach by setting up a local mirror. A recent *push it out - oops! - pull it back* episode occurred December 11 2019, and it still hasn't been fixed https://askubuntu.com/q/1196147/243321

Comment: What about using something like Timeshift (https://teejeetech.in/2017/10/01/timeshift-v17-10/)?

Answer (score 3):

In general it is risky NOT to update. This is good explained in the answer before. But how to handle the unknown risk?
Over the years I've installed a lot of hardware to test on my second system. Sometimes I've messed up the system or my kernel and the normally harmless `sudo apt-get update; apt-get dist-upgrade` becomes a nightmare.

So I started with a special setup on this machine.

```
Partition 1: / (Main OS) (25 GB)
Partition 2: / (Main OS) (25 GB)
Partition 3: SWAP (8 GB)
Partition 4: /home (150 GB)
(Partition 5: /media  (250 GB), optional)
```

So I've used Partition 1 to install Ubuntu and use it for a while. At the point I messed the system up again, I've reinstalled Ubuntu on Partition 2. The Partition 1 is unused until Ubuntu broke again.

Maybe it sounds a little harsh, the above described situation happens about only once every two years. But since I've had the possibility to easy switch, I've done it more often.
In every case the settings will survive. Not only the /home, also the individual configs from /etc and so on are easily recoverable. Downgrades are possible, but I don't recommend them.
Even the switch from Ubuntu to Debian works this way. But I won't do this too often. There are some configuration file issues due to the version differences.

The directory /media also contains a ubuntu mirror, with the needed artchitecture. A long time I lived (even in Germany), without any fast internet connection, but I've done a lot of full reinstalls.

PS: I've also leaned the hard way, not to switch too often between `apt-get`, `aptitude`, `apt`, `synamptic` and so on. Using different dpkg frontends at the same time could lead to nearly unresolveable dependency issues in the running system.

Comment: @Melebius What do you mean?

Comment: Sounds like a cool solution. But how will all the settings survive? You cannot just copy the directories (like etc/, home/ etc) to the newly installed OS, since they come with the issues, right?

Comment: Instead of having another OS installed on your hard drive, you could use a live OS on a USB flash drive to fix the main installation or reinstall it. See [Re-install Ubuntu without losing data in home folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269880/re-install-ubuntu-without-losing-data-in-home-folder) for details.

Comment: It is not the perfect solution, to heal the world, indeed. It is my personal solution, I've wanted to share as suggestion ... Of course I can use a live system and try to fix it in plenty of unpredictable hours, or just reinstall in roundabout one and a half hour - sometimes the legacy has the right to die ... And yes, you can't do `cp /mnt/etc/* /etc/`, but you can rescue nearly on the fly everything not broken (exim config, ssh settings, global rc-files, ...). Even step by step, if you'll forget anything to rescue during the initial setup.